# How to visually select based on indentation?

Tags: indentation, visual-mode, custom-text-object

If someone is editing the following javascript file:

```js
let foo = true
if (foo) {
  let bar = 42
  // moooooore code...
}
```

You can use `vi{` anywhere on the line with `let bar` to select `let bar = 42` and all other lines inside `{...}`.

However, how can I select based on indentation?

Let's take Ruby as an example:

```
def some_method
  if @foo
    @bar = 42
    # moooooore code...
  end
end
```

What command would I use to select `@bar = 42` and all other code ?

Comment: Ive used https://github.com/michaeljsmith/vim-indent-object for a while with some success. Not sure if that counts as an answer though

Comment: @D.BenKnoble good enough for me, thanks a lot :+1:

Comment: @D.BenKnoble +1. I think your comment is an actual answer. BTW it is easier for others to see if a question has got an answer when people do not place their answers in comments. I think comments are for clarifications and questions to the OP. This also disables the possibility to up/down vote to get a fast feedback.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble If you was concerned about answering by referring to a plugin, maybe following discussion on https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21/how-much-should-we-indulge-questions-about-plugins reassures you that plugin answers are on-topic.

Comment: @Hotschke thanks for the info; I know I’ve got a couple of answers to put together when I get a moment

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've used [vim-indent-object](https://github.com/michaeljsmith/vim-indent-object) for a while with some success.

It provides text objects like `ii`, `ai`, `iI`, and `aI`, each with slightly different semantics.

For your sample code

```
def some_method
  if @foo
    @bar = 42
    # moooooore code...
  end
end
```

If the cursor is anywhere inside the `if` block, you could use `vii` to select the the `bar` and `more` lines. Or, use `=ii`, `cii`, `dii`, `!ii`, `yii` &c., depending on what you want to do.