# di in vim/fortran

Tags: vimscript

I have tried without any luck, but can anyone kindly let me know if `di` is possible for language like vim/fortran which has structure like

```
   do loop
      Something
   end do
```

**UPDATE:** command `di', di", di{, di[, di(` delete content inside the given surround. So, consider the given code:

```
Program  i
Implicit None
if (<some condition>) then
  text for if block
end if  
End Program  i
```

if my cursor is inside `(<some condition>)`, and do `di(`, in normal mode, then `<some condition>` will be deleted.

So, I am looking for some similar thing, when my cursor is inside if block, and I can delete `text for if block`!

Comment: so you wan't to delete "Something"? There is always this little plugin https://github.com/jeetsukumaran/vim-indentwise which could help you

Comment: What you do expect `di` to do? Because either you are talking about the deletion command `d` and a text object like `ip` or something like this and then you didn't described the complete text object or you are talking about `:di` but I don't see how it's related to fortran. *Edit* I didn't see Doktor OSwaldo's comment but if you mean "How can I delete a paragraph based on its indentation" it would be worth it to edit your question to make it more clear.

Comment: @statox: :h object-select

Comment: With your edit now your question makes sense, thank you :)

Comment: so, can I expect some `sensible` answer? :p

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/18679/1841) (the answer is the same plugin) and I'm fairly sure we have other questions on the same topic but I can't find them

Comment: @statox: the intent was not same, but looks like that is the next best I can get. I was looking for `blockwise` rather than `intentwise`!

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the [vim-indent-object](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3037) plug-in, which allows you to select or delete blocks based on indentation.

As long as your indentation is correct (and that should be easy, since Vim has good Fortran plug-ins to indent your code correctly and the built-in Fortran indentation plugin works well enough), the vim-indent-object motions can accomplish what you describe.

If you're using a plug-in manager such as vim-plug (or Vundle), you can have them install the plug-in directly with something like `Plug 'michaeljsmith/vim-indent-object'`.

After you have it installed, you can use the **`ii`** and **`aI`** motions in your Fortran code.

Assuming this block in your code sample:

```
if (<some condition>) then
  text for if block
end if
```

And your cursor is in the first line of the block (the `if (...) then` line), then you can use **`dii`** command ("delete inside indent") to delete the block inside the `if`, which in your example means `text for if block`. (Of course, this becomes more useful as there are more lines of code and further indentation within that block, which this plug-in should handle nicely.)

Also useful is the **`daI`** command ("delete around indent", note uppercase `I`) to delete the indented block, but also the current line and one line below the block with indentation matching the current line. This is useful in Fortran, to include the matching `end if` or `end do` line. In your example, this would delete the three lines of code, the `if (...) then` line, then the indented `text for if block` and finally the `end if` block.

Of course, you can use these text objects with other operations than "delete", for instance **`Vii`** to visually select the indented block.